# Loop over string vector for graphs in R

Tags: string, r, graph, stata

I'd like to loop over a string vector called `country`, which contains country codes, such as `AFG`, `ETH`, etc.

In `Stata` the code would look like this:

```
levelsof country, local(xtry)
foreach x in local xtry:
 graph command here if xtry=="`x'"
 graph save mygraph

}
```

Is there a comparable command to `levelsof`, as well an "if" statement that restricts the data to a particular country code, which is a string, from which each graph will be created?

Comment: Your probably don't want to loop over it quite like that. You probably want something `tapply` or the `**ply` functions from the `plyr` package.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with your data, there are a family of functions that apply a function to a list, column, row, etc.. Very useful to replace many for statements.  Type ?apply into the R console.

Answer (score 3):

You would use something like this:

```
for (cn in levels(country))
    {
    if (cn=="x")
       {
       <do something>
       }
    else
       {
       <do something else>
       }
    }
```

If you want to check for multiple countries you can use

```
if (cn == "x" | cn == "y")
```

or also

```
if (cn %in% c("x", "y", "z"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, the apply group of functions is really a similar thing if not identical to constructing for loops, the thing is the apply group of functions are wrappers for such loops and are specific to different data structures and requirements - a more Rish way of doing loops. I don't know how valid the speed boost claims are - I'm skeptical. Other than that if I understand what you are asking (I don't know stata) it might be easier to subset the data with R and then do several plots for each subset.

Comment: As a Stata person I confirm that this suggestion matches the Stata content of the question. My affection for Stata on one side, it seems to me a better strategy to ask how to do something in R than to ask for a translation of Stata code. The number of R users is clearly much larger than the number of competent R users who also know Stata! However, this forum expects some code in a question; yet also showing only the code in another language implies no effort to start writing code in the language desired.

Comment: should be: The number of competent R users is clearly much larger than the number of competent R users who also know Stata!